# Rundeck ACL to hide definition

Tags: rundeck

I'm setting up an ACL to disable

[image]

and

[image]

on a specific user groups.
I'm try it with view action on Job Type, but this option disable

[image].

How can I disable download job definition and View definition without disable README button ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Right now doesn't exist a specific rule for disabling the README button on the job page using the `view` statement on your ACL definition, it seems that action takes that button as a part of restriction [to export](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1167). You can suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues). The best approach right now is to leave all info on the job description.